# Different highlight style for ESLint errors in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm 2017.3 and ESLint.

I'm wondering: is there a way to customize ESLint errors highlighting so I will be able to distinguish the WebStorm's errors (there is no closing bracket) and ESLint 'errors' (there should be a space before the bracket)?

Currently, I can not distinguish critical typos and 'advices' of ESLint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **File | Settings | Editor | Inspections**, select **ESLint**

Uncheck in Options: **use rule severity from the configuration file**

From the Severity dropdown, choose the desired severity level, or select Edit severities and set up your own severity level with desired highlighting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'Custom' severity highlighting is not supported for ESLint - [WEB-25697](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25697). **Level 1** issues (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules) are highlighted as warnings ( **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings | Warning**), **Level 2** - as errors (**Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings | Error**)

**Update**: since 2018.3, you can override severity levels from the linter's config by unchecking **Use rule severity from the configuration file** in **Preferences | Editor | Inspections | ESLint**. Please note that this way all rules enabled in the config will be highlighted the same way, without the distinction between errors and warnings. See this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25697#focus=streamItem-27-3090927.0-0